# Count votes in SQL and order by descending

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have this table in SQL which contains Meal Votes.

Table:

[image]

Now, what I want to do is count all the SAME MealId's with each other, and order them by descending.

For example (Id | MealId | UserId | VoteDate):

```
1 | 13 | 1 | somedate

2 | 1  | 2 | somedate

3 | 3  | 1 | somedate

4 | 13 | 3 | somedate
```

Now, after the counting it should be like this:

```
2  //Here are the MealId's that are equal to 13
1  //Here are the MealId's that are equal to 1 or 3, because there is only 1 vote for that Meal
1  //Here are the MealId's that are equal to 1 or 3, because there is only 1 vote for that Meal
```

NOTE: It doesn't have to show the vote counts: "2 , 1 , 1" , I just want to Order the votes by Descending. The Meal that contains most of the votes, should be on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a windowed aggregate ([`COUNT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)) to get the count data into the rows alongside the rest of the data, then just a simple `ORDER BY`:

```
;With TotalVotes as (
    select *,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY MealId) as Cnt
    from UnnamedTable
)
select * from TotalVotes ORDER BY Cnt desc,MealId
```